# Editing possibility in queries

Tags: libreoffice-base

LibreOffice 5.1.6.2

I have saved some queryes and I'd like to allow users to use them directly (without any reports). Reason: there are filters thare, they are convenient.
My users are sophisticated ones, so queries are ok.

The problem is a possibility to edit data when looking at the results of the selection.

Please, have a look at the picture:
[image]

In the tool bar there is a button called "Edit data". By default editing possibility is switched on.

I'd like to switch this editing possibility off constantly. Could you help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries can only be edited if Base can directly match up each record with a unique key.  There is a brief discussion on this topic [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/35227/edit-data-in-a-base-query/).

One simple way to prevent Base from doing this is to wrap the query in another one.  Edit the query in SQL view.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT "ID", "PlantID", "Notes" FROM "Tasks" )
```

[image: read-only query]

Even though the [Edit Data](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Edit_Data) button is not disabled, clicking on it will have no effect.  When the query is closed and opened, the button is disabled.